# Hybrid iso - can it be created by isohybrid?

Tags: boot, live-usb, iso

I trying to understand it right. [isohybrid](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/isohybrid) is a tool to make Ubuntu iso bootable - see [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb).

> Cloning an iso file to a mass storage device makes a boot drive,
>   provided it is a hybrid iso file, post-processed with isohybrid. See
>   this link to the isohybrid sub-page.

Also on same link:

> mkusb will 'use the whole device', actually only the head end (size of
>   the iso file), but the rest of the device is not available. mkusb
>   simply clones the ISO 9660 file system with its content from the iso
>   file. This ISO 9660 file system works from CD/DVD disks, and also from
>   USB drives. After using a USB pendrive like this, you make a new
>   partition table and file system, if you want to use it for another
>   purpose.

But in wikipedia [Hybrid_disc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_disc):

> A hybrid disc is an optical disc that has multiple file systems
>   installed on it, typically ISO 9660 and HFS+ (or HFS on older discs).
>   One reason for the hybrid format is the restrictions of ISO 9660
>   (filenames of only eight characters, and a maximum depths of eight
>   directories, similar to the Microsoft FAT file system).

So do I understand it correctly that `isohybrid` tool makes ordinary ISO 9660 images, not hybrid ones? What is the meaning of `hybrid` apex in `isohybrid`, why is it not called something like `isoboot`? I could not find that "historic" info via web search.

Comment: Sounds like a question for Sudodus. you can PM him @ https://ubuntuforums.org/private.php?do=newpm&u=1499021

Comment: @DK Bose: Thanks, I just gave the route we usually use. Seems to have worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Hybrid iso file and program `isohybrid`

The program [**`isohybrid`**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/isohybrid) from the package `syslinux-utils` converts

- an iso file that can be **burned to a bootable CD/DVD**

to

- a hybrid iso file, that can be

  - **burned** to a bootable CD/DVD ***and***
  - **cloned** to a bootable mass storage device: USB pendrive, USB SSD, memory card, internal HDD, internal SSD ...

It is possible to use the robust **cloning** method to create a boot drive from a mass storage device (most often a USB pendrive).

`isohybrid` adds some code near the head end of the iso image in order to make this possible.

---

Please notice that `isohybrid` should be used only once. Do not you use it on an iso file, that has already this hybrid feature. Most (but not all) linux distros are distributed as hybrid iso files.

---

I don't know the history of the word isohybrid, but I have used this tool myself, when I made bootable iso files 'from scratch', and I have used it to convert CD/DVD-only iso files for years. Nowadays I seldom use it, because most iso files that I download are already 'isohybrid' iso files, that boot also when cloned into a USB pendrive.

### Links

[wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Isohybrid](https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Isohybrid)

[wiki.osdev.org/El-Torito](https://wiki.osdev.org/El-Torito)

### A hybrid disc is something else

The link in your question about 'hybrid disc' is describing something else, not a hybrid iso file. The similar names can cause confusion.

Comment: Thanks, have not tried this myself.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron, You are welcome :-)

Comment: Hi! `isohybrid: image.iso: could not find boot record` after `mkisofs -lJR -o image.iso directory_name` directory_name is loopmounted hybrid iso that resulted in properly booting USB. What is wrong? If too complex for comment, than I see a new question is needed.

Comment: @Martian2020, It is often best to create an own question, where you can describe what you have, what you have done, what you want and what went wrong. Please put a link to the new question here.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1378005/isohybrid-image-iso-could-not-find-boot-record